# Using bottle cork as authentication with mongodb not working in python 3.10

Tags: python, bottle

I am using bottle cork as authentication and working in python 2.7 but on python 3.10 its not working

Here is the code for login

```
@bottle.post('/login')

def login():

    """Authenticate users"""

    username = post_get('username')

    password = post_get('password')

    aaa.login(username, password, success_redirect='/management/stats/today', fail_redirect='/login?failure')
```

When I do login using correct credentials I am getting 500 internal server error.

Here is the error log

```
[2022-06-09 09:45:29 +0500] [224454] [DEBUG] POST /login

<h1>Critical error while processing request: /login</h1>[2022-06-09 09:45:29 +0500] [224454] [ERROR] Error handling request /login

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/app/bin/bottle.py", line 966, in wsgi

    start_response(response._status_line, response.headerlist)

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py", line 150, in session_start_response

    session.persist()

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/session.py", line 875, in persist

    self._session().save()

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/session.py", line 723, in save

    self._create_cookie()

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/session.py", line 737, in _create_cookie

    val = self._encrypt_data()

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/session.py", line 379, in _encrypt_data

    return nonce + b64encode(self.crypto_module.aesEncrypt(data, encrypt_key))

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/crypto/pycrypto.py", line 22, in aesEncrypt

    counter=Counter.new(128, initial_value=0))

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Counter.py", line 109, in new

    initval = _encode(initial_value, nbytes, little_endian)

  File "/opt/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Counter.py", line 118, in _encode

    n = long(n)

NameError: name 'long' is not defined
```

Comment: I am looking for this n = long(n). Can you post snippet code?

Comment: Yes I have checked this but this is not application code I have written this is site-packages which is not changed. Which snippet code do you want me to send you.

Comment: OOp. Sorry, My bad.

Comment: I am not sure but the code works until this line     aaa.login(username, password, success_redirect='/management/stats/today', fail_redirect='/login?failure'). Is there any issue  with this line? I have the exact same codes running on python 2.7

Comment: I can't help you because I'm using python 3.11.0b3

Comment: Ok no issue thanks for your time

Comment: Did you install `pycrypto` yourself? Or was it brought in by some other package as a dependency? Pycrypto hasn't been supported for years and is not compatible with Python3.

Comment: No I did not install pycypto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time.

I installed pycryptodome using pip install pycryptodome and the error is gone.